# Ipython in emacs dumps trash text into shell

Tags: emacs, ipython

When I launch an ipython process in an emacs buffer, it prints trash text to the buffer:

```
^[[J^[[?7h^[[?12l^[[?25h^[[?2004l
^[[?12l^[[?25h
```

The ipython buffer does this every time I launch it, every time I evaluate code in another buffer, every time I evaluate code in that buffer. Ipython never does this from the bash CLI, `In [1]:`

Where could I look to change this behavior to a more sensible and terse prompt, such as what ipython does in bash?

This is in emacs 24.5.1 inside tmux 2.0 with python 2.7.6, ipython 5.1.0, python-mode version 6.2.1, running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Here's every line in my .emacs file that even mentions python:

```
; (require 'python-settings)

; (require 'ein)

(setq py-install-directory "~/.emacs.d/python-mode")

(add-to-list 'load-path py-install-directory)

(require 'python-mode)

(setq python-shell-interpreter "~/anaconda2/bin/python"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "-i console --matplotlib")

(setq-default py-shell-name "ipython")

(setq-default py-which-bufname "IPython")

; use the wx backend, for both mayavi and matplotlib
(setq py-python-command-args
  '("--gui=wx" "--pylab=wx" "-colors" "Linux"))

;; responsible for the annoying window rearrangement behavior after every code execution? Nope.

(setq py-force-py-shell-name-p t)

; switch to the interpreter after executing code

(setq py-shell-switch-buffers-on-execute-p nil)

(setq py-switch-buffers-on-execute-p nil)

(setq py-shell-local-path "/home/ftamborello/anaconda2/bin/python"
      py-use-local-default t)

; don't split windows

(setq py-split-window-on-execute-p nil)


; try to automagically figure out indentation

(setq py-smart-indentation t)

; enable flycheck syntax support

; (add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
```

Comment: When calling IPython from inside a python-mode, not from plain shell, this shouldn't happen. Please report it as bug if it still occurs.

Comment: If you're using Emacs' 'inferior shell' mode, it's not fully compatible with the new terminal interface IPython uses (prompt_toolkit). You can launch it in an emacs terminal, or use the `--simple-prompt` option to disable the clever terminal interaction.

Comment: I'm using IPy mode defined in python-mode.el version 6.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

what Thomas K suggests is the actual solution, just edit your init.el file and paste the following:

```
RUN IPYTHON6.4 IN EMACS ALONG WITH PYTHON3+
(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython3"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "-i --simple-prompt")
```

Comment: It seems like OP is using python-mode.el, which is different than the python.el that Emacs ships with.